# Contractor did not tile under shower seat

Tags: shower

Asked some friends who have contracted in the past or are on par DIYers who could contract but have other employment. All said it doesn't look right but they also said you are probably okay. Contractor said he would come back and tile it, however it is better as he left it this way and lets it breathe.

[image]

Comment: It may be a reginal thing, but in 5 decades of tearing out and tiling showers, I have never seen one that was left untiled like that.

Comment: I mean, unless you sprayed the water on there, it clearly gets wet.  I can't imagine that the joint between the 40 mil and the top tiles is waterproofed.

Comment: I would get him back to finish it.

Answer (score 3):

The liner is what makes a shower waterproof. The tile just makes it easier to look at. Whether the contractor needs to tile it depends on what’s in your contract.